# Possible to retrieve only a portion of xml data loaded with ajax?

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I have my application loading and parsing my xml data with ajax, but I only want to return a specific number of values - starting with the first.

I feel like I should be able to specify what I want here:
    `$(xml).find("person").each(function()`

I almost got what I needed by including .first():
    `$(xml).find("person").first().each(function()`

But that only loads the first instance, whereas I need the first ten. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Seems like the first should work. Can you show some of the XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [slice](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/slice) function to reduce the set of matched elements to a subset specified by a range of indices. Then apply a function to each element as usual:

```
$(xml).find('person').slice(0,9).each(function () ... )
```

Comment: I thought his problem was that he wasn't getting anything, maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: @Barmar I thought that `$(xml).find('person').first()` worked, so I presumed it was just a matter of limiting the number of elements... but perhaps I was the one who misunderstood?